# Send/Recieve message from .net socket to signalR hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sockets, signalr

We have windows server application sending the message through the socket(System.Net.Sockets) to clients with socket(windows applications). And Now we want send message from server to web application using Asp.net SignalR.

How can we achieve this with SignalR? Please suggest with code snippet and architecture.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't. The current version of SignalR relies on HTTP and follows [this protocol](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/). You won't be able to connect to the server if you don't follow the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with SignalR using `Hub`. Fist, install SignalR from NuGet Package Manager.

In your Startup.cs file, add

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

Create your Hub class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public string msg = "Initializing hub...";

    public void CallLongOperation(int progressStatus)
    {
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jsonMessage = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(@"{
                      'msg': 'message',
                      'value': "someValue"}");
        Clients.Caller.sendMessage(jsonMessage.ToString());
    }
}
```

Next, in your controller, get `MyHub`instance and you can notify clients:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(jsonMessage.ToString());
```

Note that you have to create Json object (you can do it like in `MyHub` class)

Finally, accept message in your javascript file:

```
var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;
progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (message) {
     // Do whatever you want with message you sent from server
        }
    };
```

You should add script in your `html` page. (You got this script from SignalR)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will help...